# Custom Leaf Nodes with Text Input in PrimeNG TreeSelect Component

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

I'm working with a dynamic form that includes the PrimeNG Treeselect component. The data structure for this component consists of two layers, essentially a list of lists. I would like to enhance the Treeselect component by incorporating a text input within the nodes.

Here are the specific requirements:

1. If all elements of a node are selected, I want to display a text input or some custom template on that node.
2. If a leaf is selected, I want to show a text input.

Here's the existing code snippet:

```
<div class="field grid">
    <label [for]="field.controlName" class="col-12 mb-2 md:col-4 md:mb-0 font-bold">{{ field.label }}</label>
    <div class="col-12 md:col-8">
        <p-treeSelect class="md:w-20rem w-full" [id]="field.controlName"
                      containerStyleClass="w-full"
                      [formControl]="control"
                      [options]="field.nodes"
                      placeholder="Select Item"
                      [metaKeySelection]="false"
                      selectionMode="checkbox"
        >
        </p-treeSelect>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here's an image representing the current state:
[image]
I appreciate any guidance on achieving this customization.

Answer (score 1):

Since [treeselect](https://primeng.org/treeselect) is not supporting templating at the moment(there's any reference on official documentation), the only way to achieve your goal is to use a simple tree with massive [template customization](https://primeng.org/tree#template).

Then you can add [selection checkboxes](https://primeng.org/tree#checkbox) and listening to [events](https://primeng.org/tree#event) in order to apply your own custom behaviour.